# Django: Defining custom fields to work with Angular Material

Tags: python, django, django-forms, angular-material

I'm working on an existing Django project to upgrade it's GUI to [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/). I've used Django forms and model forms throughout the project and now it's very difficult to write the Angular Material like custom tags and widgets in the templates to replace each form. So, I was trying to write some code which can covert all my default Django form fields to Angular Material tags.

I found two ways of doing so:

1. Writing a new render function say `as_md()` with a custom `def _html_output()`, similar to `as_ul()` or `as_p()` by
       inheriting Form/ModelForm class. This will convert the complete form fields to the new material tags, however this is a less flexible way (in case I want to change the layout for some of the forms).
2. Writing custom widgets to render each field as per my requirement.
   This will require writing custom widget for each field type.

Can there be some other way to implement this in a more efficient way? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Fields

If you need the two way data binding, your fields will each need an `ng-model` to keep the binding intact. Writing custom widgets will help you achieve this.

But to make sure all your forms will use these custom widgets, a custom render function will work great.

---

### django-angular

If you're looking for something with less hassle, take a look at the [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) project, it aims to achieve the same thing.